# It there 32-bit version of OpenCL (any vendor) for Linux?

Tags: linux, opencl, word-size

Bypassing the obvious "why??", does anyone know of any 32-bit versions of OPENCL from Nvidia or Intel for Ubuntu?

I looked but, i could not find anything recent. Have they finally just jumped to 64-bit only?

Thanks, 
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The AMD App SDK](http://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) allows you to execute OpenCL on your CPU.
Otherwise you can try out [pocl](http://github.com/pocl/pocl) which also allows OpenCL execution on your CPU.

[Beignet](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/) (OpenCL on Intel GPUs) might compile on a 32bit linux.

Probablye you also need an OpenCL ICD like this one: [khronos](http://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader)

That said, I recommend that you move to a 64bit system, I could imagine that especially with OpenCL where vectorization is important you might loose quite some performance, since you cannot use all AVX/AVX2 registers on x86-32.

Best Regards,
Michael

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using a 64 bit linux, i just need the 32bit OpenCL runtime and drivers.